# How does Universal/Existential instantiation work with multiple statements?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

So, say you're given ∃x P(x) and ∀x Q(x)-->˜P(x). I want to use this given statements in a formal proof. To manipulate them in the way I want to, I believe I need to use instantiation to remove the quantifiers. However, I am not sure how that works with these separate quantifiers (using the same variable and domain).

If I turn the first statement into P(c), can I also turn the second statement into (Q(c)-->˜P(c))?

Comment: Is that tilde (~) supposed to be a negation sign ($\neg$)? Also, is your second statement missing a pair of brackets? Is it meant to be $\forall x[Q(x)\rightarrow\neg P(x)]$?

Comment: Just as a quick comment the $x$ in $\exists x P(x)$ has nothing to do with the $x$ in $\forall x(Q(x)\implies \neg P(x))$. You might want to use $y$ for one just to realize it. This doesn't prevent you from instantiating the way you do (assuming the brackets are as we assume rather then as you wrote them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, universal instantiation gives you (with minor inconsquential variations in phrasing)

$$ (\forall x \; \phi) \to \phi[x\mapsto t] $$
for *any term $t$ whatsoever* of your own choosing (as long as $[x\mapsto t]$ denotes proper capture-avoiding substitution).

You're definitely allowed to let $t$ be a term that already has a role in your proof -- such as one you got from instantiating $\exists x\, P(x)$ *earlier* in the proof.